# Python String - Passing parameter to .__contains__ from a list

Tags: python, string, list, contains

I have a list of strings like so:

`filterlist = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]`

I want to loop through this and check if any one of these strings is present as part of another string like

`test_str = "An Apple a day keeps the Doctor away"`

This is what I tried and succeeded:

```
for f in filterlist:
    if test_str.__contains__(f):
        doSomething()
```

But I tried doing the following and it didnt work:

```
if test_str.__contains__(f for f in filterlist):
    doSomething()
```

What is the difference between the first and second technique? What does `f for f in filterlist` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False.

```
>>> test_str = "An Apple a day keeps the Doctor away"
>>> filterlist = ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"]
>>> any(i in test_str for i in filterlist)
True
```

Comment: Do you mean use `any` in place of `__contains__` ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're using `in` instead of `__contains__` - this could be written `any(test_str.__contains__(i) for i in filterlist)`. The `any` is replacing the `for` loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you! That clears up everything :)

Answer (score 3):

> What does `f for f in filterlist` do?

It's a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), it creates a *generator* object:

```
>>> type(x for x in [])
<type 'generator'>
```

`test_str.__contains__(f for f in filterlist)` is literally checking whether that generator is in `test_str`*; which, given that *you've only just created it*, it's inevitably not going to be.

As [Avinash has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394167/3001761), using `any` is the correct way to convert your first code to a single line.

* *note that `foo.__contains__(bar)` is usually written, more clearly, as `bar in foo`*